# send a notification one hour prior to appointment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5

In my application, I am trying to do something like this,

When a meeting is scheduled, a mail is sent out with the details. This is working already.

Addition to this, I would also like to send out a mail and message prior to one hour before the meeting.

How can I do this?

Should I calculate the time from meeting_scheduled_time when the meeting details are saved and then maybe set a cron on schedule? I am not able to see a approach to do this, efficiently.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the approach you suggested and there's nothing inefficient about it if you implement it properly. Just setup a job that runs periodically and checks if there are any email notifications to be sent for any scheduled meetings. Laravel even has [Task Scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) to make something like this easier to implement.

Comment: So, how do I set the job at that particular time? Suppose, there are three meetings notifications should be sent out at 12 PM, 5 PM, 6 PM. The cron should only at these times and do the job.

Answer (score 0):

A year is passed since you asked your question and now many things have been changed, [laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) introduced [Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications) which does what you ask for, you can notify into [different channels](http://laravel-notification-channels.com/) like telegram, sms and..
however, you need cron jobs since you are scheduling your notifications.

Hope it help others :)